# Compare the similarity of flow and rhythm of 2 songs

Tags: theory, rhythm, sound, melody

First off, I apologize if I'm not able to articulate my question correctly or effectively due to my lack of knowledge on music terms.

My friends and I were having an argument about whether two foreign songs we were listening to had very similar flow and rhythm/style, and we were pretty split evenly on people who agreed they sound similar and people who don't hear it that way. To me personally, I thought it was very clear how the second song seemed to have the same flow and rhythm/style.

This had me wondering, there must be some way to do an analysis where the songs can generate some graph, and we can compare the graphs. Is my thought valid? And if it is, what tools could I use to do such an analysis, and what data would I want the graph to be generating?

Comment: Could you share the sheet music with us?

Comment: Even just links to YouTube videos of the songs could help. A lot of songs can share the same basic rhythms and have little else in common, so hearing the song or reading the sheet music would help.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the names of the songs, and my friend has them in MP3 file. I will ask him for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This had me wondering, there must be some way to do an analysis where the songs can generate some graph, and we can compare the graphs. Is my thought valid?

Sure.  You can graph the songs' pitches (Y-axis) over time (X-axis) to compare them.

That's what a score is.  A musical score is a peculiar sort of notation for graphing pitch over time for the playback and analysis of music.

Comment: Any particular suggestion on tools that I could use to easily produce such a graph using the songs?